# How DO I fetch last Week and current week

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I fetch last week data from monday time (00:00:01) and end on sunday time (23:59:59)...
same as this current week from monday time (00:00:01) and end on sunday time (23:59:59)

WHat I tried!

```
$query = "SELECT users.name,count(*) as count, 
                 campaign.campaign_name, 
                 campaign.payout_cost*count(*) as totalPrice
            FROM users 
            JOIN transactions on users.uid=transactions.uid 
            JOIN campaign on campaign.campaign_id_id=transactions.campaign_id 
           WHERE uid=$uid 
             AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+6 DAY)   
             AND `date` <  DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY) 
           GROUP BY campaign.campaign_name_name ";
```

Comment: This looks an awful lot like PHP combined with MySQL. In that case, you should really make use of Prepared Statments and Parametized queries using either mysqli or PDO. Structuring a query with a direct injection of a variable (especially if input based) opens you up to a potential SQL Inject Attack (SQLI Attack).

Comment: I'm still learning  but anyway thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track by avoiding functions like `week()` on the column -- that just messes up the optimizer.  On the other hand, the `uid` parameter should be passed as a *parameter* rather than munging the query string.

You want to use the `weekday()` function because you want weeks to start on a Monday.  Just some arcaneness of MySQL:  `weekday()` returns `0` for Monday whereas `dayofweek()` returns `2` for Monday.

So, the logic for the current week would be:

```
date >= curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day and
date < curdate() + interval 7 - weekday(curdate()) day
```

For last week, this would be:

```
date >= curdate() - interval 7 + weekday(curdate()) day and
date < curdate() + interval - weekday(curdate()) day
```

Notes that `curdate()` (or `current_date`) returns the current date with no time component, so no `date()` is required.

Comment: Tried this. But not working "select
  count(*) as count,
  sum(campaign.payout_cost) as total
from transactions
join campaign on campaign.campaign_id = transactions.campaign_id WHERE uid=$uid AND 'dateTime' >= curdate() - interval weekday() day and
'dateTime' < curdate() + interval 7 - weekday() day"

Comment: What is `'datetime'`?  That is not correct syntax and there are no single quotes in this answer.

Comment: So the value must be date.. the dateTime is from the column.. so thats wrong then?

Comment: but it gives me blank

Comment: $query = "select campaign.campaign_name,
  count(*) as total_count,
  sum(campaign.payout_cost) as total_payout
from transactions
join campaign on campaign.campaign_id = transactions.campaign_id  WHERE uid=$uid AND date >= curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day and
date < curdate() + interval 7 - weekday(curdate()) day GROUP BY campaign_name
 ";

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do it...

```
select data from tableName
where date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();

select data FROM tableName
wherdate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WEEK()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php) function, which returns the week number for a given date, by adding

`AND WEEK(date-INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 1` to get current week's data starting from monday upto sunday,

and

`AND WEEK(date-INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 2` for the previous week's data

into the `WHERE` condition after `WHERE uid=$uid`

such as

```
$query = "SELECT c.campaign_name,
                 COUNT(*) as total_count,
                 SUM(c.payout_cost) as total_payout
            FROM transactions t
            JOIN campaign c
              ON c.campaign_id = t.campaign_id
           WHERE uid = $uid
             AND WEEK(date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 1               
           GROUP BY c.campaign_name ";
```

*and replace `WEEK(NOW()) - 1` with `WEEK(NOW()) - 2`, also*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ded47579bd022220b4bebebc224a953)</kbd>

Comment: it gives me blank   "$query = "select
  count(*) as count,
  sum(campaign.payout_cost) as total
from transactions
join campaign on campaign.campaign_id = transactions.campaign_id WHERE uid=$uid AND WEEK(date-INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 1
 ";"

Comment: same here "$query = "select campaign.campaign_name,
  count(*) as total_count,
  sum(campaign.payout_cost) as total_payout
from transactions
join campaign on campaign.campaign_id = transactions.campaign_id WHERE uid=$uid GROUP BY campaign_name AND WEEK(date-INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 1
 ";"

Comment: I told you need to add into the WHERE condition, not to the GROUP BY list. I have edited @marcomasx , have a look at that please.

Comment: Okay buddy thanks! I tried it but still giving me blank :( I dont whats the problem..

Comment: This is the whole query

Comment: Still got blank :(  " $query = "select campaign.campaign_name,
count(*) as total_count,
sum(campaign.payout_cost) as total_payout
from transactions
join campaign on campaign.campaign_id = transactions.campaign_id  
WHERE uid=$uid AND WEEK(date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 1
GROUP BY campaign_name
 "; "

Comment: Anyone please! It return into a blank

$query = "SELECT c.campaign_name,
                 COUNT(*) as total_count,
                 SUM(c.payout_cost) as total_payout
            FROM transactions t
            JOIN campaign c
              ON c.campaign_id = t.campaign_id
           WHERE uid = $uid
             AND WEEK(date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = WEEK(NOW()) - 1               
           GROUP BY c.campaign_name ";